# NEXT.JS - Server Error: Must use import to load ES Module: C:\Users\...\nextjs-blog\node_modules\remark\index.js

Tags: módulo-ecmascript, next.js

Galera, segui o tutorial do site oficial do Next.js nesse link ( https://nextjs.org/learn/basics/dynamic-routes/render-markdown ) e obtive o seguinte erro:
"Server Error
Error: Must use import to load ES Module: C:\Users\Gustavo\Documents\VSCODE\Next.js\Next.js Tutorial\nextjs-blog\node_modules\remark\index.js
require() of ES modules is not supported.
require() of C:\Users\Gustavo\Documents\VSCODE\Next.js\Next.js Tutorial\nextjs-blog\node_modules\remark\index.js from C:\Users\Gustavo\Documents\VSCODE\Next.js\Next.js Tutorial\nextjs-blog.next\server\pages\index.js is an ES module file as it is a .js file whose nearest parent package.json contains "type": "module" which defines all .js files in that package scope as ES modules.
Instead rename C:\Users\Gustavo\Documents\VSCODE\Next.js\Next.js Tutorial\nextjs-blog\node_modules\remark\index.js to end in .cjs, change the requiring code to use import(), or remove "type": "module" from C:\Users\Gustavo\Documents\VSCODE\Next.js\Next.js Tutorial\nextjs-blog\node_modules\remark\package.json.

This error happened while generating the page. Any console logs will be displayed in the terminal window. "

Pelo que entendi existe algum problema com os comandos import ou require, mas eu usei import do início até o ponto do link sem erro. Nesse passo do link o blog parou de funcionar.

Agradeço por qualquer ajuda. O código está em: https://github.com/profglac/Next-blog

Comment: Coloque o pedaço de código para ser analisado também.

Answer (score -1):

consegui descobrir o problema. Atualizei a versão da dependência 'remark' de 14.0.0 para 13.0.0 e o problema foi resolvido. Abaixo o arquivo package.json final para o caso de alguém ter esse problema.
{
"name": "learn-starter",
"version": "0.1.0",
"private": true,
"scripts": {
"dev": "next dev",
"build": "next build",
"start": "next start"
},
"dependencies": {
"date-fns": "^2.23.0",
"gray-matter": "^4.0.3",
"next": "^11.0.0",
"react": "17.0.2",
"react-dom": "17.0.2",
**"remark": "^13.0.0",**
"remark-html": "^13.0.1",
"unified": "^10.1.0"
}
}